# Suggest users based on common interest - MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Basically what i am trying to do is to suggest people based on common interests.

I have a table of Users(id, username, firstname, lastname, etc)

I have a table of Interested_People where UserID + Interested_in is stored.

I have a table of Contactlist where people who are added with each other is stored.(user1, user2, accepted [1,0])

What I want is to select * users table who are not my friend and they have same interest with me as well.

I searched a lot in internet but couldn't find something like so.

```
Here i do have created a query and it does exactly what I want. But it is very slow. Even it takes 16 to 20 second to output in PHPMyAdmin in my local machine. Now I Kindly request you guys if you can edit my query a bit and make it bandwidth & time efficient.

SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  id IN(SELECT userid 
             FROM   interested_people 
             WHERE  interested_in IN(SELECT interested_in 
                                     FROM   interested_people 
                                     WHERE  userid = [userid]) 
                    AND id NOT IN(SELECT user1 AS my_friends_userid 
                                  FROM   contactlist f 
                                  WHERE  f.user2 = [userid] 
                                    AND accepted = 1 
                                  UNION 
                                  SELECT user2 AS my_friends_userid 
                                  FROM   contactlist f 
                                  WHERE  f.user1 = [userid] 
                                    AND accepted = 1)) 
       AND id != [userid] 
ORDER  BY Rand () 
LIMIT  0, 10;
```

[Userid] in this query is the ID of the user who is online. Like if i m online my ID will be 1.

This query suggest 10 random users who are not my friends and have same interests as me. But very slooow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Have you tried to run explain with your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem suggests a self-join to get the users with common interests.  Then, `not exists` to avoid the contact list.  The following gets the list of users with common interests, ordered by the number of common interests:

```
select ip2.userid, count(*) as numInCommon
from interested_People ipme join
     interested_People ip2
     on ipme.interested_in = ip2.interested_in and
        ipme.userid = $UserId and  -- Your user id goes here
        ip2.userid <> ipme.userid
where not exists (select 1 
                  from contactlist cl
                  where cl.user1 = ipme.userid and cl.user2 = ip2.userid and
                        cl.accepted = 1
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from contactlist cl
                  where cl.user1 = ip2.userid and cl.user2 = ipme.userid and
                        cl.accepted = 1
                 )
group by ip2.userid;
```

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "not" at position 228)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "exists" at position 232)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 239)

Comment: @user2765602 . . . There is nothing that looks like a syntax error near the `not`.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I ditched the square brackets